# Toolstrip - overflow menu size

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms Toolstrip with the property 'CanOverflow' enabled. Items that don't fit in the toolstrip, are moved into the drop-down overflow menu. Is there a way to control the size of the Overflow menu?

I have a vertical toolstrip and there are currently too much items in it. Some items don't fit on the screen and have become inaccessible. I want to adjust the width, because it can show multiple items on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a multicolumn table layout in a DropDown menu by setting the ColumnCount of the TableLayoutSettings, for example:

```
ToolStripDropDown drop_down = new ToolStripDropDown();
// ...add your huge number of ToolStripItems to drop_down.Items here
drop_down.LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.Table;
((TableLayoutSettings)drop_down.LayoutSettings).ColumnCount = 2; // Or whatever you need
menu_item.DropDown = drop_down;
```